# Prove that there is a positive number $B$ such that $|x_{n}| \geq B$ for all $n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

$[{x_n}]^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is a sequence of real numbers that converges to $x_0$ and that all $x_n$ and $x_0$ are nonzero.

I have done the following:

for all $n$ in $|x_{n}|\geq B$

$x_0 < B$

$\epsilon<B-x_o$

$\epsilon+x_o<B$

for all $n$ in $N\geq  n \in  I_{\epsilon}(x_0)=[x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon]$

$|x_{n}|\geq B$ contradicts $\epsilon+x_o<B$

Would this be a reasonable approach?

I am fairly new to this side of mathematics and have been having trouble with proofs. Introductory Analysis is a pre-requisite to my further studies in Economics which is why I am attempting to learn it.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to prove.

Comment: @Fred upon further reading my answer really doesn't make sense. I don't think I have understood the question either in that case.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $|x_n|\le B$?

Comment: @ Koro I'm sure - it is a practice question from the textbook "Mathematics for Economists - Simon & Blume; pg260, 12.7" for reference. Unless it is a typo.

Comment: What do you want please state it clearly.

Comment: OK @Nish: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are learning introductory analysis I will advise you to express the arguments in plain natural language.

Try to grasp this fact

> If $x_0$ is non-zero (eg say $1,2,-0.005$ or $10^{-20}$) then it is at a specific distance from $0$ and there is a range of numbers which lie between $0$ and $x_0$. Thus if we get too close to $x_0$ we move far away from $0$.

The sequence in question converges to $x_0$ and thus the terms $x_n$ (after a certain value of $n$, say $m$) can be ensured to lie very close to $x_0$ and thus far away from $0$. Your ask how close to $x_0$? Well, just choose any specific number, say $A$, between $0$ and $x_0$ and then one ensures that the terms $x_n$ for all $n\geq m$ do not lie in the range between $0$ and $A$, but rather between $A$ and $x_0$ or on the other side of $x_0$.

This way we ensure that $|x_n|\geq |A|$ for $n\geq m$. Now choose $B$ to be the minimum of $|A|, |x_1|,|x_2|,\dots,|x_{m-1}|$ (each of these is positive so that $B$ is also positive) and then we have $|x_n|\geq B$ for all $n$.

In such a situation we say that sequence $x_n$ is *bounded away from zero*.

---

If you have understood the above you will realize that $\epsilon, \delta$ stuff of analysis is just an unambiguous way to present the same argument. While it does require some experience to convert the informal argument into a formal one, this translation is not the rigor part of analysis and one should not focus too much on it. Rather the focus should be on rigor and key ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: There exists $k$ such that $|x_n|>\frac {|x_0|} 2$ for all $n  >k$.  (Choose $k$ such that $|x_n-x_0| <\frac {|x_0|} 2$ for $n >k$). Let  $B$ be the minimum of $\frac {|x_0|} 2$ and $|x_1|,|x_2|,..., |x_k|$. Can you show that $|x_n| \geq B$ for all $n$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $x_n$ converges to $x_o$,we have :
For every $\epsilon\gt 0, \exists N_{\epsilon} $ such that for all $n\ge N_{\epsilon} $, we have :
$|x_n-x_o|\lt \epsilon$ 
By triangular inequality, $||x_n|-|x_o||\le |x_n-x_o|$ and hence by choosing $\epsilon =|x_o|/2$,we get:

$||x_n|-|x_o||\lt |x_o|/2 \implies |x_0|-|x_o|/2\lt |x_n|\lt |x_o|+|x_o|/2\implies |x_n|\gt|x_o|/2$  
Hence, $|x_n|\gt |x_o|/2$ for all $n\ge N_{\epsilon=|x_o|/2}$
Let $B= min\{|x_1|,|x_2|,...,|x_{(N_{\epsilon=|x_o|/2 }-1) }|,|x_o|/2\}$ 
Hence, $|x_n|\ge B$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$

Comment: Thank you for this - I will need to read it through a few times to internalize the steps.

Comment: I have 2 questions about this: 1) How do we decide that $\epsilon = |x_0|/2$, 2) Why is there a minus 1 In the minimum function for B for the $x_N$ term $x_{(N_{\epsilon=|x_o|/2 }-1) }$

Comment: @Nish: 1) Idea is to get a lower bound for $|x_n|$, if you don't like $|x_o|/2$, you may take $|x_o|/3$ etc. also. 2) Because, we know (we have shown so) that  $N_{\epsilon} $th term onwards, every term is $\gt |x_o|/2$ but we have no idea about terms coming before $|x_{N_{\epsilon}} |$ but since $N_{\epsilon}$  is finite, we can take minimum of all terms before $|x_{N_{\epsilon}} |$, which are $|x_1|,...,|x_{N_{\epsilon - 1}}|$ and then this minimum can be compared with $|x_o|/2$ to get $B$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $x_n \to x_0$ as $n \to \infty$. Then, by definition, for any $\epsilon > 0$,

$$
\exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n \geq N, | x_n - x_0 | < \epsilon
$$

If we choose $\epsilon = |\frac{x_0}{2}|$ we get that for all $n \geq N$

$$
|x_n - x_0| < |\frac{x_0}{2}| \Longrightarrow |x_n| \geq |\frac{x_0}{2}|
$$

If you struggle to see why this is true you can separate it into $x_0 >0$ and $x_0 < 0$ and work it out from there.

Then, you will have that for all $n$,

$$
|x_n| \geq \min \{|x_1|, |x_2|, ..., |x_N|, |\frac{x_0}{2}|\} > 0
$$